# How do you add a photo album to a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-groups

How do you add a photo album to a Facebook group? If the option doesn't exist, is there a viable option?

Comment: I concur with Answer #0.  Many discussion groups exist about this.

Answer #1 doesn't even answer your question.  They answered the question "how do you post photos", not "how to create a photo album" in groups.

I'm guessing that since none of us pay for FB, that there probably isn't much concern for what we want.  We are not their customers...the people who give them money are.

Comment: @kevin: You realize that answers can be listed by date, activity, votes, etc.? Thus referring to them by number makes no sense at all, since they can be in any order?

Answer (score 2):

You are only able to post photos to a Facebook group if the group admin allows it.  If photo uploads are allowed you can upload a maximum of five photos at a time. There is no limit on moving photos between albums.

[From the Facebook FAQ Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12610)

> **How do I post photos to a group?**
>
> Group admins can select whether photos
>   can be posted to a group from the
>   Customize tab of the Edit Group page.
>   If photos are enabled, admins may
>   allow all group members or only other
>   admins to post them. Admins also have
>   the ability to remove any photos they
>   do not want to be associated with
>   their group.
>
> If you are allowed to add photos, you
>   can do this by clicking the "Photos"
>   icon in the Publisher at the top of
>   the group’s main page. You can select
>   up to five photos at a time to upload,
>   or move as many photos as you want
>   from an existing album. If this is an
>   open group, the photos will be visible
>   to everyone who views the group.
>   Photos posted on closed and secret
>   groups are only visible to other
>   members.

Comment: I am the admin of my Group. There is no "Customize" tab on the Edit Group page...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if Facebook changed the interface or something. But the following works for me:

To share an album from your profile:

1. On your own personal FB profile page, click on the “HOME” icon in the blue bar at the top of the page (brings you to your newsfeed page)
2. Click Photos in the left sidebar.
3. Click on ‘Albums’
4. Click on the particular Album you wish to share (this shows thumbnails of all the photos in the album)
5. Click the Share link (just below the thumbnails)
6. Click on the bar with the title ‘On your own timeline’ to present a drop down menu and select ‘In a group’.
7. Begin to type in the group name, and when the group name appears in a blue bar proceed to click on that blue bar.
8. Then just click "Share Album" button.

To create an album directly in the group:

1. Go to the group.
2. Click on View Photos option on the right sidebar
3. Click Upload Photos button on the top right of the page
4. Select photos to upload as usual and click
5. At this point Facebook will start uploading the selected photos and allow you to name the album. (shows a progress bar)
6. Click the "Create Album" button at the bottom of the dialog (you can do this even while the upload is in progress)
7. Once the photos are uploaded and the progress bar completes, the album is ready